# JpGraph font file error

Tags: php, mysql, jpgraph

I am trying to insert a graph after reading my DB.

The problem is that I get the following error:
[image]

I already tried changing the permission in my jpgraph folder without succes.
In my local computer it is working fine but once it is in the server it shows this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that your server actually has the font file required?
Try `ls -l /usr/share/fonts/truetype/verdanab.ttf` on your server to check. You probably need a font package called corefonts. On debian that's available throuh `apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Comment: I checked the server and I don't have this folder. But in my local computer I don't have this folder either and it is working!. Strange uh?

Comment: It's probably somewhere else. From the font type I'm guessing you run MS Windows on your local system? Should be in `c:\windows\fonts` (or distributed with jpgraph, I'm not sure right now).

Comment: I checked details in jpgraph and for windows enviroments it gows to windows/font that is my computer folder. The server is not Windows and goes to folder that shows on error message. I will change the font folder and try in the server. Thanks!

Comment: its alive!!! :)   I update my file adding the line define('TTF_DIR','../jpgraph/fonts/'); and it worked!